# Cypher query gets slower if the part of the graph gets smaller

Tags: neo4j

My Graph consists of *Thing*, *Link* and *Tag* nodes. A *Thing* can be *:CONNECT* ed to *Link* s and *Tag* s.
The graph is around 45GB in size with 4mio nodes and 84mio relationships.
Nodes consist only of one field with an key for external system reference.

I am looking for *Thing* s (t2) in my Graph that are strongly connected to another *Thing* (t1) via a *Link*.

The Cypher query is for example:

```
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"}) 
MATCH p=(t1)-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing) 
WHERE t1<>t2 WITH t2, count(DISTINCT p) AS links 
RETURN t2, links 
ORDER BY links DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t2                                                       | links |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[166590]{key:"4b06471e-0849-4e56-b5c9-6bc04730c899"} | 854   |
| Node[190480]{key:"8934c635-17de-449a-9437-a24857b8b1c6"} | 698   |
...
| Node[754437]{key:"925b4f3a-0c69-46b9-8f35-294b9539a98b"} | 345   |
| Node[656436]{key:"50424c32-8ce8-495b-a8d3-f4864b1c3adc"} | 342   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
25 rows
18232 ms
```

Performance is not very very amazing. But that is not the main problem for me at the moment.

I like now to look for *Thing* s (t2) in my Graph that are strongly connected to another *Thing* (t1) via a *Link* and connected to a specific *Tag*.

```
MATCH (tag:`Tag` {key: "da8115ff-95fb-46d7-bd14-24bdd16f0a04"}) 
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"}) 
MATCH p=(t1)-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing)-[:CONNECT]->(tag) 
WHERE t1<>t2 
RETURN t2, count(DISTINCT p) AS links 
ORDER BY links DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

The problem is, that this query runs forever. In my opinion this should run faster than the first Cpyher query because the part of the graph I am interested in is much smaller?

I am using Neo4j 2.1.2 running on a 80GB SDD, 16GB RAM for Java, 16GB RAM for the OS with 4 cores.

Comment: I think you should really change your relationship-types, as being connect to a link and to a tag are two different things and if you don't select by rel-type it is much slower.

Comment: The Graph is now updated and the query MATCH (tag:`Tag` {key: "da8115ff-95fb-46d7-bd14-24bdd16f0a04"})  MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"}) MATCH (t1)-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link) MATCH (l)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing) WHERE t1<>t2 MATCH (t2)-[:TAG]->(tag) WITH t2, count(l) AS links ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25 RETURN t2, links; runs now within 14962 ms. Any ideas how this can be tuned?

Comment: Can you share your profile for that query? I.e. go to localhost:7474/webadmin/console and prefix your query with "profile"

Comment: try this: MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link) 
WITH distinct t1,l
MATCH (l)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing) 
WHERE t1<>t2 
WITH distinct t2
MATCH (t2)-[:TAG]->(tag:Tag {key: "da8115ff-95fb-46d7-bd14-24bdd16f0a04"}) 
RETURN t2, count(l) AS links 
ORDER BY links DESC 
LIMIT 25;

Comment: and you're sure you have an index both for :Tag(key) and :Thing(key) ?

Comment: PROFILE for first query https://gist.github.com/michaelwittig/928e0c6c1662daeb7562

Comment: your suggested query takes around 30 seconds (I modified it a bit because l was not piped til the end of the query where the count is calculated). the PROFILE can be found here https://gist.github.com/michaelwittig/0eaf7436d3bbf6fe141c

Comment: :schema => Indexes
  ON :Attribute(key) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Link(key)      ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Tag(key)       ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Thing(key)     ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having 2 different relationship-types would help.

Do you have an index or constraint on `:Tag(key)` ?

**How many paths** are returned when you don't limit / order them? What's the performance difference if you just use limit without order?

```
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})-[:CONNECT]->
      (l:Link)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing) 
RETURN t2, count(DISTINCT p) AS links 
ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25
```

Can you try the new, experimental query planer on your query?

```
CYPHER 2.1.experimental
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})-[:CONNECT]->
      (l:Link)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing) 
RETURN t2, count(DISTINCT p) AS links 
ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25
```

**Update**

Try this:

```
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})-[:CONNECT]->(l)
WITH distinct l,t1
MATCH (l)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2)  
WHERE t1<>t2  
RETURN t2, count(distinct l) AS links  
ORDER BY links DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: I have Unique constraints on the key attribute.

Answer (score 0):

My fastest version after watching http://vimeo.com/84900121 is:

```
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"}) 
MATCH (t1)-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link) MATCH (l)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing) 
WHERE t1<>t2 WITH t2, count(l) AS links 
ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25 RETURN t2, links
```

and takes 7520 ms.

Using the new, experimental query planer:

```
CYPHER 2.1.experimental 
MATCH (t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})  
MATCH (t1)-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link)  
MATCH (l)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing)  
WHERE t1<>t2  
WITH t2, count(l) AS links  
ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25  
RETURN t2, links
```

takes 11942 ms

Your query

```
MATCH p=(t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing)  
RETURN t2, count(DISTINCT p) AS links  
ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25
```

takes 13315 ms removing ORDER BY does not have an effect.

Using the new, experimental query planer:

```
CYPHER 2.1.experimental  
MATCH p=(t1:Thing {key: "a80b3828-6fec-4031-b552-d3397d1737b7"})-[:CONNECT]->(l:Link)<-[:CONNECT]-(t2:Thing)  
RETURN t2, count(DISTINCT p) AS links  
ORDER BY links DESC LIMIT 25
```

takes 21200 ms.

A typical result looks like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t2                                                       | links |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[166590]{key:"4b06471e-0849-4e56-b5c9-6bc04730c899"} | 854   |
| Node[190480]{key:"8934c635-17de-449a-9437-a24857b8b1c6"} | 698   |
| Node[153785]{key:"476f9756-e829-495c-82a2-6d05efa24a5a"} | 665   |
| Node[217705]{key:"4e69f054-3828-4c9c-829d-bc1b94499d26"} | 595   |
| Node[434466]{key:"372832f9-338b-4818-b7df-f60ec68e0dbc"} | 586   |
| Node[188948]{key:"ed023053-9c4d-4978-b884-cd7a77f9d610"} | 580   |
| Node[129093]{key:"49dfa255-8455-4f90-962d-63e9244b4337"} | 576   |
| Node[249272]{key:"fbdcbba8-c47d-4e4d-bae1-0ebadf6e7692"} | 553   |
| Node[253605]{key:"4c7848aa-eff7-4cd8-ab1e-79cb9a17fe59"} | 533   |
| Node[149177]{key:"9e5e830e-8ebd-456d-9e0c-094b5fc6964b"} | 519   |
| Node[155016]{key:"0d1148ff-3040-4c45-8198-a5918dd96721"} | 503   |
| Node[346978]{key:"640812b0-996e-4a1b-9a55-80417b010403"} | 478   |
| Node[256312]{key:"a16b233f-e363-4883-bc4c-9ccb1e4d1738"} | 463   |
| Node[203843]{key:"e739384f-0b1d-4f47-9abb-debfdc438796"} | 421   |
| Node[632642]{key:"8788d644-11ff-4a49-805e-32268183a712"} | 420   |
| Node[222103]{key:"eb4cdb73-67b7-46aa-a26f-1612a855a7d4"} | 419   |
| Node[156930]{key:"1ee362fb-0308-45e4-9dbc-1286e4571cb9"} | 414   |
| Node[445506]{key:"c1d50c68-748c-4551-ab4f-7313bf38ec70"} | 407   |
| Node[205489]{key:"fcf2f12a-b6cf-4d74-afbc-b75f1e57dd40"} | 384   |
| Node[134227]{key:"d44a2c49-35dd-44c1-82cb-c1386bb1beec"} | 368   |
| Node[360284]{key:"8fbed168-9183-455e-8869-350fbf9310f4"} | 365   |
| Node[223032]{key:"4424b8e8-d4aa-43dc-8b21-d6c119645092"} | 359   |
| Node[769577]{key:"8b538f97-8152-4552-aa6a-eadd78cfbe9c"} | 358   |
| Node[754437]{key:"925b4f3a-0c69-46b9-8f35-294b9539a98b"} | 345   |
| Node[656436]{key:"50424c32-8ce8-495b-a8d3-f4864b1c3adc"} | 342   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Changing the Relationship Type will take some time :) So I will come back later with numbers for that.